# Hibernate Generic Dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics

I want to write abstract class, which will contains all generic methods for working with db like save, update and etc. After that create as many implementations as many DAO's I need, and, if needed, overwrite/add methods.

```
public interface Dao<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    void save(T t);

    T get(ID id);

    void update(T t);

    void remove(T t);

    List<T> findAll();
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T, ID> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public AbstractDao(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void save(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);
    }

    public T get(ID id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    public void update(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(t);
    }

    public void remove(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(t);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).list();
    }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDao extends AbstractDao<User, Integer> {
    public UserDao() {
        super(User.class);
    }
}

public class MainTest {
        @Test
        public void testName() throws Exception {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HibernateConfig.class);
            UserDao userDao = ctx.getBean(UserDao.class);

            ...
        }
    }
```

And I get this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.sevak-avet.UserDao] is defined
```

If I don't use AbstractDao class and implement all methods directly in UserDao, it works. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `com.sevak-avet` is not a valid package name, that might be your cause - have you seen if the actual generated classes are within that?

Comment: you should use Interface Dao to get bean from context, Spring can't use classes to casting

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, It's not copy-paste, I have valid package in project :)

Comment: @IgnatGalkin Yes, it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Sevak.Avet you wellcome:)

Comment: Use Spring Data JPA instead, don't reinvent the generic dao again...